# how to display 2 fields value in same column : visual force

Tags: salesforce, visualforce

I'm using below code in salesforce to display 2 fields value in same column but getting error "Error    Error: Incorrect parameter type for operator '+'. Expected Text, received Object"

**`<apex:column value="{!item.Assigned_Queue__c + item.Assigned_To__c}" headerValue="Assigned To"/>`**

I tried with Below code Also but it gives me "Error: Incorrect parameter type for function 'TEXT()'. Expected Number, Date, DateTime, received Text" . Please suggest an option for this.

**`<apex:column value="{!item.Assigned_Queue__c + TEXT(item.Assigned_To__c)}" headerValue="Assigned To"/>`**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

below solution worked for me .

**

```
<apex:column headerValue="Assigned To">
                    {!item.Assigned_Queue__c}<br></br>
                    {!item.Assigned_To__c}
</apex:column>
```

**